# Consuming and replying to separate queues | Pika implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, queue, pika

I am struggling to solve my issue, hope anyone from the community can help me here.

Our requirement is locked and can't be changed as the producer publishing the queues is controlled by a different team.

Producer which is written in JAVA declares three queues (TASK, RESPONSE, TASK_RESPONSE) and listens on them with the help of spring framework.

A hashmap is sent to the TASK and TASK_RESPONSE queue from the java AMQP client (Producer).

We need to consume these hashmaps and send the responses as follows.

- If the queue TASK is processed, the response needs to be sent on RESPONSE queue incrementally.
- If the queue TASK_RESPONSE is processed, the response needs to be sent on TASK_RESPONSE queue incrementally (RPC mode).

Now, we need to consume and publish this in python since we need to do some background processing on the tasks.

I tried to work with celery and dramatiq, but was not able to figure out how it can be done with them, so I tried writing myself (with the help of tutorials available online)

Problem is, I am able to consume the messages but not able to reply_to the RESPONSE queue. Here is my code.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import pika
import datetime
import logging
import json
from logging import StreamHandler
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from pika import SelectConnection

from settings import *

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[StreamHandler()], level=logging.INFO, format=logging.BASIC_FORMAT)
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class QueueConsumer(object):
    """The consumer class to manage connections to the AMQP server/queue"""

    def __init__(self, queue, logger, parameters, thread_id=0):
        self.channel = None
        self.connection = None
        self.queue_name_task = queue['task']
        self.queue_name_response = queue['response']
        self.logger = logger
        self.consumer_id = 'Consumer Thread: %d' % (thread_id,)
        self.parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(**parameters)

    def consume(self):
        try:
            self.connection = SelectConnection(parameters=self.parameters, on_open_callback=self._on_connected)
            self.connection.ioloop.start()
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error('{} {}'.format(self.consumer_id, str(e)))
            self.connection.close()
            self.connection.ioloop.start()

    def _on_connected(self, connection):
        connection.channel(on_open_callback=self._on_channel_open)

    def _on_channel_open(self, channel):
        self.channel = channel
        try:
            # Declare Task Queue
            self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue_name_task,
                                       exclusive=False,
                                       durable=True,
                                       auto_delete=False,
                                       callback=self._on_queue_declared)
            self.logger.info("{} Opened Channel....".format(self.consumer_id))

            # Declare Task Response Queue
            self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue_name_response,
                                       exclusive=False,
                                       durable=True,
                                       auto_delete=False)
            self.logger.info("{} Opened Channel....".format(self.consumer_id))
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error('{} {}'.format(self.consumer_id, str(e)))

    def _on_queue_declared(self, frame):
        self.logger.debug('{} ... declaring queue'.format(self.consumer_id))
        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        try:
            self.channel.basic_consume(queue=self.queue_name_task,
                                       on_message_callback=self.handle_delivery,
                                       auto_ack=True)
            self.logger.info("{} Declared queue...".format(self.consumer_id))
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error('{} crashing:--> {}'.format(self.consumer_id, str(e)))

    def handle_delivery(self, channel, method, header, body):
        try:
            start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            _logger.info("Received...")
            _logger.info("Content: %s" % body)
            req = json.loads(self.decode(body))

            # Do something
            sleep(randint(10, 20))

            time_taken = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
            log_msg = "[{}] Time Taken: {}.{}".format(req['bar']['baz'], time_taken.seconds, time_taken.microseconds)
            _logger.info(log_msg)

            # Publish the result to another queue.
            try:
                self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                                           routing_key=self.queue_name_response,
                                           properties=pika.BasicProperties(),
                                           body=log_msg)
                _logger.info("Message Published...\t(%s)" % self.queue_name_response)
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.error('{} Message publishing failed:--> {}'.format(self.consumer_id, str(e)))

        except Exception as err:
            _logger.exception(err)

    def decode(self, body):
        try:
            _body = body.decode('utf-8')
        except AttributeError:
            _body = body

        return _body


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pika_parameters = OrderedDict([
        ('host', TF_BROKER_HOST),
        ('port', TF_BROKER_PORT),
        ('virtual_host', TF_BROKER_VHOST)
    ])

    queue = {'task': TF_IAAS_TASK_QUEUE, 'response': TF_IAAS_REPLY_QUEUE}

    try:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=TF_IAAS_THREAD_SIZE, thread_name_prefix=TF_IAAS_THREAD_PREFIX) as executor:
            start = 1
            for thread_id in range(start, (TF_IAAS_THREAD_SIZE + start)):
                executor.submit(QueueConsumer(queue, _logger, pika_parameters, thread_id).consume)

    except Exception as err:
        _logger.exception(err)
```

*Publish Messages On RabbitMQ*

```py
import pika
import json
import random
import datetime
from faker import Faker
from random import randint

fake = Faker('en_US')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
                host='localhost'))
        channel = connection.channel()

        channel.queue_declare(queue='tf_task', durable=True)
        started_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        properties = pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2)
        for i in range(0, 10000):
            body = {
                'foo': randint(i, i+100),
                'bar': {
                    'baz': fake.name(),
                    'poo': float(random.randrange(155+i, 389+i))/100
                }
            }

            channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                                  routing_key='tf_task',
                                  body=json.dumps(body),
                                  properties=properties)
            if i%10000 == 0:
                duration = datetime.datetime.now() - started_at
                print(i, duration.total_seconds())
        print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
        connection.close()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        duration = now - started_at
        print(duration.total_seconds())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: "not able to reply_to the RESPONSE queue" - what does that mean? Do you get errors? Do messages just not show up? Is anything logged by RabbitMQ that is suspicious?

Comment: I do not get any errors. My messages are not going on the reply queue, i.e RESPONSE queue. Also, in celery reply_to has a known issue. https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3848

Comment: Is the `RESPONSE` queue bound to the defalt `amq.direct` exchange using `tf_task` as the routing key? If not, messages won't be routed there based on the code you have provided.

Comment: How do I bound it? Can you provide an example? That would be really helpful.

Comment: If you are not creating any custom exchange, `RabbitMQ` will be using the default direct exchange. In that case, you must provide your queue name as the routing key while publishing the message. Try setting the routing key as `response` and publish the message.

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding correctly. In the producer code, I push the messages on the `tf_task` queue. In the consumer code, I retrieve the message from the `tf_task` queue and once the task is processed, I try to push it to the `response` queue. In consumer, when I publish the result I am setting `routing_key` to `response`.